# Replace text of all csv's in all the subfolders

Tags: vba, excel, csv, dir

I have a code to replace text of all files in the folder. But i also need to replace the text in all the subfolders. How do i it?

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Pathname = "C:\Users\pabitra.pradhan\Downloads\RATES\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.csv")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    DoWork wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
With wb
    .Worksheets(1).Select
    Cells.Replace What:="MDL04", Replacement:="MDL05", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You might find it easier to use `FileSystemObject` to recurse subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the same recursive like that:

```
Sub ProcessFiles(myFolder As String)

Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Filename = Dir(myFolder & "*.csv")
  Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFolder & Filename)
    DoWork wb
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
 Loop

Dim FSfolder As Folder 

Set FSfolder = FS.GetFolder(myFolder ) 

For Each mySubFolder In FSfolder.SubFolders
    Call ProcessFiles(FSfolder.Path)
Next

End Sub
```